# How to open new tabs instead of splits by default in VIM?

Tags: vim, whitespace, indentation, text-cursor

I have installed [rust.vim](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim) and it has the `:Crun` command, which opens a split when called. Is it possible to open a new tab instead of a split? If it is possible, how to do it? (I know that it is possible to call `C-w T` to switch to tab mode, but I'd like to have this automated)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found out: `autocmd BufNew * wincmd T`

Comment: But with a reason: I use VIM from my phone (laptop isn't always accessible, and there are no dedicated rust editors with autocompletion and local compilation on Android), so I don't want to split my screen, it's small already. And why I can't change something if I don't like it? I don't think that I will ask a question like this just because I wanna customize something for fun